# Print all possible paths using BFS + no more than K edges far

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm

> I see similar solution is available in [All Possible paths K edges far](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-possible-paths-source-destination-exactly-k-edges/)
>   . But I am looking for experts guidance - how to solve each of the
>   following constraints over the common question :

```
a)It should be a clever BFS solution 
b)The signature should be at least **printAllGraphPaths( Node source, Node target,....)** [not integer] 
c)Source and target should be internal nodes [not like source having zero in-degree and target with zero out-degree]
```

<s>d)Nodes though can be different instances but can have same value</s>`

```
e)Result can't be more than K edges. 
f)Same node can be visited multiple times (eg. Node(2) )
```

<s>g)Can have cycles</s>

[image: Graph]

Given source = 1 & target = 3, then printAllPossiblePaths :

```
    1 -> 2 -> 3    
    1 -> 5 -> 3
    1 -> 5 -> 2 -> 3   
    1 -> 6 -> 5 -> 2 -> 3
    1 -> 6 -> 5 -> 3

  for duplicate node 5 there will be three more extra paths
    1 -> 5 -> 2 -> 5 -> 3 
    1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 3
    1 -> 6 -> 5 -> 2 -> 5 -> 3
```

> Follow-up additional Question:

1. What is better DFS or BFS in which situation and why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will outline a clever solution for you, but not implement it.

The goal is to be able to print paths but not waste time in enumerating paths that don't want up in the right place.  So you want a data structure that looks like this:

```
by node
    by length of remaining path
        list of nodes you could go to to get to the desired target.
```

No matter how many paths there are, this data structure is polynomial in size and can be generated in polynomial time using standard dynamic programming techniques starting with the *target* (not the source).  This will be a breadth-first algorithm.

Now you take your source node and `k`.  And using this data structure you can do a depth-first search through the data structure, printing paths as you go.  This will take time proportional to how much data you are printing.  But you will never be going down a wrong turn and exploring paths that do not work.

Bonus optimization.  The algorithm that I described will work.  But for the special case of very large graphs and very short `k` (think "path from person A to person B in a large social network") it can be improved substantially.  The improvement is to start from the target and go back `ceil(k/2)` and start from the source and (by reversing the path structure) and go forward `floor(k/2)`.  Store the fringe of both in a hash structure.  And now we walk through the intersection of the fringes, and construct the paths in both directions.

This optimization can always be done.  But won't be an improvement except in the one special case.

To see why it is an improvement, suppose that you have 50 average connections per person and you are trying to find a path of length 6 from you to the President.  The first version that I described basically winds up having to construct a data structure the size of the whole social graph.  Which is quite literally billions of things.  But with the bonus optimization you draw a circle whose size is in the hundreds of thousands from you, and another of the same size from the President then intersect them.  The preprocessing step therefore takes less than a million operations.  Which is much better than billions!

Comment: what is meant by length of remaining path :  (K - no_of_levels_traversed +1) ?

Comment: @ArnabDutta Logically yes.  But note that we are starting from the target, not the source, and working backwards.  So the length of the remaining path is actually the length of the path that we have worked out so far.

Comment: Understood...thanks ...makes full sense...and brilliant intersecting nodes

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully created my solution code!
Feel free to discuss and suggest to improve its complexity (time & space) or some better approach. People might find its over engineered but my point was...in real life who inputs two ints as src and dest ? I needed solid Nodes too:

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;

public class AllPathsAdhocSrcDestNodes{

    List<List<Integer>> allPaths = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<List<Integer>> bfs(Graph g, Node src,Node dest,int m){
        int depth =0; List<Integer> tempPath = null;

        Queue<Node> q = new ArrayDeque<>();
        src.path.add(src.value);
        q.add(src);

        while(!q.isEmpty()){ 

            Node u = q.poll();                
            depth = u.depth;  

            if (depth > m)
                continue;

            if(u.value == dest.value && depth <= m){
                allPaths.add(u.path);
            } 

            List<Node> neighbours =  g.adjMap.get(u);
            for(int k=0;k<neighbours.size();k++){
              Node v = neighbours.get(k);
              tempPath = new ArrayList<>(u.path);
              tempPath.add(v.value);
              q.add(new Node(v.value,u.depth+1,tempPath));

            }

        }
        return allPaths;
    }

   /*------------------------ Driver program ---------------------------------*/     
        public static void main(String[] args){
        // List of graph nodes & edges as per diagram
            Node[] n = { new Node(0),new Node(1),new Node(2),new Node(3),new Node(4),new Node(5),new Node(6),new Node(7) };


            Edge[] e = {
                            new Edge(n[0], n[6]), 
                            new Edge(n[0], n[1]), 
                            new Edge(n[1], n[6]),
                            new Edge(n[1], n[5]), 
                            new Edge(n[1], n[2]), 
                            new Edge(n[2], n[3]),
                            new Edge(n[3], n[4]), 
                            new Edge(n[5], n[2]), 
                            new Edge(n[5], n[3]),
                            new Edge(n[5], n[4]), 
                            new Edge(n[6], n[5]), 
                            new Edge(n[7], n[6]),
                            new Edge(n[7], n[1])
                        };



        // construct graph : Graph acc to CLRS is G(V,E) nothing else
          Graph g = new Graph(Arrays.asList(n),Arrays.asList(e));

        //inputs
          Node src = n[1], dest = n[3];
          int m = 4;

        // Do modified BFS traversal from source vertex src
          AllPathsAdhocSrcDestNodes tester = new AllPathsAdhocSrcDestNodes();
          System.out.println(tester.bfs(g, src, dest,m));
    }


    public static void printQ(Queue<Node> q,int k){
        System.out.println(k+"queue:"+q);
    }
}

class Edge{
    Node source, dest;

    public Edge(Node source, Node dest) {
        this.source = source;
        this.dest = dest;
    }
}

class Graph{
    List<Node> vertices;
    List<Edge> edges;
    HashMap<Node,List<Node>> adjMap = null;

    Graph(List<Node> vertices,List<Edge> edges)
    {
        this.vertices=vertices;
        this.edges=edges;

        int N = vertices.size();

        adjMap = new HashMap<>(N);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            adjMap.put(vertices.get(i), new ArrayList<>());
        }

        // add edges to the directed graph
        for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++){            
            Node src = edges.get(i).source;
            Node dest = edges.get(i).dest;

            adjMap.get(src).add(dest);
        }
    }
}

class Node{
        int value;
        int depth;
        List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<>(); //path from root till this node just for printing we dont need List<Node>

        public Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Node(int value,int depth,List<Integer> tempPath) {
            this.value = value;
            this.depth = depth;
            this.path = tempPath;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj){
            if(obj == null || !(getClass()==obj.getClass()) ||  this.value != ((Node)obj).value )
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode(){
            return this.value;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(value);
        }
}
```

Drop a comment if you liked my effort

Comment: I am keeping my answer not accepted and will wait for better solutions